# How to synchronize MyViewController code to Java in Android Studio using Intel's Multi-OS Engine

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, intel

I am following 
[this tutorial provided by intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/633240). At step 13, the instructions say:

> Go back to Android Studio and right click on the QuizApp project, click Multi-OS Engine Actions and choose Synchronize to Java.

I am unable to find such menu. Instead here is a [screenshot of the menu that I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIkAi.png) Essentially I am trying to link the UI I created in Xcode with the java code counterpart in my common module.

I am currently running android studio version 3.0.1 with multi-os engine plugin version 1.4.1 and OS X 10.11.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

You have to create a binding instead.

[Context Menu - create binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6cvj.png)

This will generate a .nbc file, where you can add the header files of your native code.

[binding.nbc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE32A.png)

Do not forget the import statement in the "Import headers" section.

After you added all your bindings you can generate the Java classes.

[Generate Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4urg.png)

Maybe this link can help you as well.
https://discuss.multi-os-engine.org/t/no-synchronize-to-java-menuepoint/1440